# What is the purpose of this spiral wire on top of the transformer body?

Tags: power-supply, transformer

A follow-up to [What are the ratings of vintage Selenium Rectifier B20/16-2,4?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98086/what-are-the-ratings-of-vintage-selenium-rectifier-b20-16-2-4/)

The photograph linked shows, in the red-box, a spiral wire on the transformer body[image: spiral wire on the transformer body]. 
What is the purpose of this?

p.s. I vaguely recall a similar (pardon my language!) contraption on top of a sub-station transformer - think it may have been at a Railway yard.

Comment: I think I fail to see the transformer .. can you zoom out a bit?

Comment: This is the top of the transformer. I'll get another photo, and post it.

Answer (score 2):

It's *probably* a hand-wound inrush/current limiting resistor.

Basically, it's a big, low-resistance power resistor used to limit the inrush current when the device is plugged in.

Since this is part of a battery charger, and not a device with significant internal capacitors, it's probably more to protect the rectifier in the case of an output short then limit inrush current.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a home-made power resistor (made from something like [Nichrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome)).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It shows like an "equipotential connection" for earth (PE). May there is some similar connection in the chassis or case.